# Python TeleBot media editing

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

people!

So, i'm using [PyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) and i need to edit media (photo in my case) in my bot's message, so i tried this thing:

```
bot.edit_message_media(message_id=M_ID, chat_id=C_ID, media=MY_MEDIA)
```

If i try to pass `message.photo[0].file_id` from another message (i mean, photo is already on the telegram server), or if i even try to create `InputMedia` object from scratch like that:

```
new = types.InputMedia
new.media = message.photo[0].file_id
```

In both scenarios, if i print `file_id`, it will show this long id string, so it's not missing.
But i still get this error:

```
2020-12-23 08:22:16,889 (__init__.py:489 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: parameter "media" is required"
```

But i did set the media parametr.... what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, i've found the solution.
When you are passing new media, do it like that:

```
from telebot import types

bot.edit_message_media(message_id=M_ID, chat_id=C_ID, media=types.InputMediaPhoto(file_id))
```

This works... wow!

Comment: and `file_id` is image path?